# lit web component localization using lit-translate

Tags: javascript, lit

I am using **lit-localization**(https://www.npmjs.com/package/lit-translate) to change component language. But all  documentations and demos are using typescript.

If anyone have done web component localization using **lit-translate**, please share it how you did it using javascript.
If not what is the solution to localize my web component.

https://github.com/andreasbm/lit-translate

Comment: lit is based off TypeScript unfortunately, so I'd suggest either learning Typescript, or dropping lit.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].

Comment: @mplungjan Rishni has been an SO member for almost 4 years.

Comment: @connexo Standard text - OP does not behave as a seasoned user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this issue following [this](https://github.com/andreasbm/lit-translate/issues/6) document. using npm dedupe.

There shouldn't be multiple **lit-html**  maintained inside node_modules folder. runing npm dedupe , it Searches the local package tree and attempts to simplify the overall structure by moving dependencies further up the tree,

**npm ls lit-html**

```
a
+-- b <-- depends on c@1.0.x
|   `-- c@1.0.3
`-- d <-- depends on c@~1.0.9
    `-- c@1.0.10
```

**npm dedupe**

```
a
+-- b
+-- d
`-- c@1.0.10
```

so running npm dedupe solved my issue.
Thanks.